# unable to connect to salesforce using java

Tags: soap, java

I am using external system as java and trying to integrate to salesforce in eclipse

```
package com.example.samples;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.DescribeGlobalResult;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.DescribeSObjectResult;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Field;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.FieldType;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.GetUserInfoResult;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.PicklistEntry;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;
public class QuickstartApiSample {
    private static BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    EnterpriseConnection connection;
    String authEndPoint = "";
    private QueryResult qr;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: com.example.samples."
                               + "QuickstartApiSamples <AuthEndPoint>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        QuickstartApiSample sample = new QuickstartApiSample(args[0]);
        sample.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        // Make a login call
        try {
            if (login()) {
                // Do a describe global
                describeGlobalSample();
                // Describe an object
                describeSObjectsSample();
                // Retrieve some data using a query
                querySample();
                // Log out
                logout();
            }
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void querySample() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    // Constructor

    public QuickstartApiSample(String authEndPoint) {
        this.authEndPoint = authEndPoint;
    }

    private String getUserInput(String prompt) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            result = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean login() throws ConnectionException {
        boolean success = false;
        String username = getUserInput("Enter username: ");
        String password = getUserInput("Enter password: ");
        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        System.out.println("AuthEndPoint: " + authEndPoint);
        config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
        connection = new EnterpriseConnection(config);
        printUserInfo(config);
        success = true;
        return success;
    }

    private void printUserInfo(ConnectorConfig config) throws ConnectionException {
        GetUserInfoResult userInfo = connection.getUserInfo();
        System.out.println("\nLogging in ...\n");
        System.out.println("UserID: " + userInfo.getUserId());
        System.out.println("User Full Name: " + userInfo.getUserFullName());
        System.out.println("User Email: " + userInfo.getUserId());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("SessionID: " + config.getSessionId());
        System.out.println("Auth End Point: " + config.getAuthEndpoint());
        System.out
        .println("Service End Point: " + config.getServiceEndpoint());
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void logout() throws ConnectionException {
        connection.logout();
        System.out.println("Logged out.");
    }
    /**
    * To determine the objects that are available to the logged-in user, the
    * sample client application executes a describeGlobal call, which returns
    * all of the objects that are visible to the logged-in user. This call
    * should not be made more than once per session, as the data returned from
    * the call likely does not change frequently. The DescribeGlobalResult is
    * simply echoed to the console.
    */

    private void describeGlobalSample() throws ConnectionException {
        // describeGlobal() returns an array of object results that
        // includes the object names that are available to the logged-in user.
        DescribeGlobalResult dgr = connection.describeGlobal();
        System.out.println("\nDescribe Global Results:\n");
        // Loop through the array echoing the object names to the console
        for (int i = 0; i < dgr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(dgr.getName());
        }
    }

    /**
    * The following method illustrates the type of metadata information that can
    * be obtained for each object available to the user. The sample client
    * application executes a describeSObject call on a given object and then
    * echoes the returned metadata information to the console. Object metadata
    * information includes permissions, field types and length and available
    * values for picklist fields and types for referenceTo fields.
    */

    private void describeSObjectsSample() throws ConnectionException {
        String objectToDescribe = getUserInput("\nType the name of the object to "
                                               + "describe (try Account): ");
        // Call describeSObjects() passing in an array with one object type
        // name
        DescribeSObjectResult[] dsrArray = connection
        .describeSObjects(new String[] { objectToDescribe });
        // Since we described only one sObject, we should have only
        // one element in the DescribeSObjectResult array.
        DescribeSObjectResult dsr = dsrArray[0];
        // First, get some object properties
        System.out.println("\n\nObject Name: " + dsr.getName());
        if (dsr.getCustom())
            System.out.println("Custom Object");
        if (dsr.getLabel() != null)
            System.out.println("Label: " + dsr.getLabel());
        // Get the permissions on the object
        if (dsr.getCreateable())
            System.out.println("Createable");
        if (dsr.getDeletable())
            System.out.println("Deleteable");
        if (dsr.getQueryable())
            System.out.println("Queryable");
        if (dsr.getReplicateable())
            System.out.println("Replicateable");
        if (dsr.getRetrieveable())
            System.out.println("Retrieveable");
        if (dsr.getSearchable())
            System.out.println("Searchable");
        if (dsr.getUndeletable())
            System.out.println("Undeleteable");
        if (dsr.getUpdateable())
            System.out.println("Updateable");
        System.out.println("Number of fields: " + dsr.length);
        // Now, retrieve metadata for each field
        for (int i = 0; i < dsr.length; i++) {
            // Get the field
            Field field =new Field();
            // Write some field properties
            System.out.println("Field name: " +getName());
            System.out.println("\tField Label: " + field.getLabel());
            // This next property indicates that this
            // field is searched when using
            // the name search group in SOSL
            if (field.getNameField())
                System.out.println("\tThis is a name field.");
            if (field.getRestrictedPicklist())
                System.out.println("This is a RESTRICTED picklist field.");
            System.out.println("\tType is: " + field.getType());
            if (field.getLength() > 0)
                System.out.println("\tLength: " + field.getLength());
            if (field.getScale() > 0)
                System.out.println("\tScale: " + field.getScale());
            if (field.getPrecision() > 0)
                System.out.println("\tPrecision: " + field.getPrecision());
            if (field.getDigits() > 0)
                System.out.println("\tDigits: " + field.getDigits());
            if (field.getCustom())
                System.out.println("\tThis is a custom field.");
            // Write the permissions of this field
            if (field.getNillable())
                System.out.println("\tCan be nulled.");
            if (field.getCreateable())
                System.out.println("\tCreateable");
            if (field.getFilterable())
                System.out.println("\tFilterable");
            if (field.getUpdateable())
                System.out.println("\tUpdateable");
            // If this is a picklist field, show the picklist values
            if (field.getType().equals(FieldType.picklist)) {
                System.out.println("\t\tPicklist values: ");
                PicklistEntry[] picklistValues = field.getPicklistValues();
                for (int j = 0; j < field.getPicklistValues().length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("\t\tValue: "
                                       + picklistValues[j].getValue());
                }
            }
            // If this is a foreign key field (reference),
            // show the values
            if (field.getType().equals(FieldType.reference)) {
                System.out.println("\tCan reference these objects:");
                for (int j = 0; j < field.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t" + getReferenceTo()[j]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private String[] getReferenceTo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;

    }

    public QueryResult getQr() {
        return qr;
    }

    public void setQr(QueryResult qr) {
        this.qr = qr;
    }

    /*
    private void querySample() throws ConnectionException {
    String soqlQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact";
    QueryResult qr = connection.query(soqlQuery);
    boolean done = false;
    if (qr.getSize() > 0) {
    System.out.println("\nLogged-in user can see "
    + qr.getRecords().length + " contact records.");
    while (!done) {
    System.out.println("");
    }
    }
    }     
    com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.SObject[] records = qr.getRecords();
    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
    Contact con = (Contact)records[i];
    String fName = con.getFirstName();
    String lName = con.getLastName();
    if (fName == null) {
    System.out.println("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + lName);
    } else {
    System.out.println("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + fName
    + " " + lName);
    }
    }
    if (qr.isDone()) {
    boolean done = true;
    } else {
    qr = connection.queryMore(qr.getQueryLocator());
    } 
    catch(ConnectionException ce)
    {
    ce.printStackTrace();
    }    
    */
}
```

I am not getting any errors but i am getting

> Usage: com.example.samples.QuickstartApiSamples

** in developer console as output.

i had used enter user name..to login and go to the next step but i am  not getting output??

Comment: How do you run your QuickstartApiSample?
Do you use command-line?
It seems you don't feed any arguments for it, that's why the control goes into the first if block.